# Processing Azure Data Factory Event Trigger Properties

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a data factory which triggers based on storage blob event. In the triggered event, I see two properties TriggerTime and EventPayload. As I have need to read the Storage Blob related information I am trying to process the EventPayload in the Data Factory. I would like access a property like 'url' from the data tag.

A sample payload looks like this:

```
{
   "topic":"/subscriptions/7xxxxe5bbccccc85/resourceGroups/das00/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/datxxxxxx61",
   "subject":"/blobServices/default/containers/raw/blobs/sample.parquet",
   "eventType":"Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated",
   "id":"a1c320d7-501f-0047-362c-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "data":{
      "api":"FlushWithClose",
      "requestId":"5010",
      "eTag":"0x8D82743B5D86E72",
      "contentType":"application/octet-stream",
      "contentLength":203665463,
      "contentOffset":0,
      "blobType":"BlockBlob",
      "url":"https://mystorage.dfs.core.windows.net/raw/sample.parquet",
      "sequencer":"000000000000000000000000000066f10000000000000232",
      "storageDiagnostics":{
         "batchId":"89308627-6e28-xxxxx-96e2-xxxxxx"
      }
   },
   "dataVersion":"3",
   "metadataVersion":"1",
   "eventTime":"2020-07-13T15:45:04.0076557Z"
}
```

Is there any short hand for processing the EventPayload in the Data Factory? For example, the filename and folderpath of an event can be accessed using @triggerBody() in the Data Factory. Does this require custom code like Azure function?

Comment: In Logic Apps this would look like trigger()['outputs']['body']['data']['url'], but Data Factory isn't nearly as friendly to JSON. You may want to move the trigger to a Logic App and have the Logic App execute the Data Factory.

Comment: @Joel Cochran, I got a response from Microsoft on this and posted that as an answer.